# Changing PHP mail ( ) to PHPMailer (deadletter.io)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to setup an email bot the code their guide provides here https://deadletter.io/learn/tutorials/parcel-email/ always sends them straight to spam.

They mention using PHPMailer but don't provide an example, could anybody explain how to update this code to use PHPMailer

```
  $to = $_POST['recipient'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
  $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

  $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

  if( $retval == true ) {
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
  }else {
    echo "Message could not be sent...";
  }
```

Comment: PHPMailer is external Library which you need to include in your project.
below is example list: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps